# Minimum Excluded Value of subarray

Tags: c++

`mex` here refers to the [minimum excluded value of an array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mex_(mathematics)).

I have and array with about 300000 elements. Then I have 50000 pairs of a and b (1<=a<300000 b<=300000) and computer need to tell me the MEX of array in range from a to b.

Example:

```
int a[10]={0,1,2,3,0,4,5,4,8,6};
a=3;
b=8;
```

We start from a[2] end and at a[7] , and MEX will be 1

I made a funtion, but it takes 30 seconds for one pair which is not what I need.

```
int Mex=0;
vector<int> a;
// fill vector
while (find(a.begin(),a.end(), Mex )!= a.end())
{
    Mex++;
}
cout << Mex;
```

So the quextion is: how to make fast MEX function with C++, so that computer can do 50000 various MEX operations for 300000 elements in 5 seconds? Memory limit is 900MB.

Comment: Could you clearly define what "mex" is? At first I thought it was a typo of "max", but from your example I'm no longer sure. [This definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mex_(mathematics)) looks feasible?

Comment: Yes Mex is this thing from wiki. But I need to make MEX not for all array, but for elements in range from a to b. Like an example from element №2 to element №4

Comment: Remember in C++ it's usually better to use `std::vector` or `std::array` than a C-style array.

Comment: According to the examples in that wiki, shouldn't the array be sorted? (I might be wrong, I'm not familiar with this definition).

Comment: Well, in my example array can not be sorted because I need to find MEX of range from one element to anouther but not the MEX of all array.

Comment: what about sorting the range and then finding the mex from the sorted range?

Comment: As I understand there is no MEX function in C++ and it is not necessary to sort array to find MEX.

Comment: A lot of mexes require RMQ datastructure.

Comment: Also, in your example you say `a = 3 and b = 8`, does that mean that the range starts from `a[3] and ends at a[8]`? Because right after that you say that it starts at 2 and ends at 4, which doesn't comply to the values `a and b`.

Comment: If a=3 and b=8 that means range is from a[2] to a[7]

Answer (score 0):

Here I am sorting the range, then trying to figure out mex.

```
int mex(std::vector<int>& num_list, int start, int end) {
    std::vector<int> range_list(num_list.begin() + start, num_list.begin() + end);
    std::sort(range_list.begin(), range_list.end());
    int mex_val = 0;

    for (auto&el : range_list) {
        int diff = el - mex_val;

        if (diff > 1) {
            break;
        }

        mex_val++;
    }

    return mex_val;

}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int>data = {0,1,2,3,0,4,5,4,8,6};
    cout<<mex(data, 3, 8)<<"\n";

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, thanks its faster that my function, but still it is too long for 300000 elements and 50000 pairs and I think thats because of sort. :(

Answer (score 0):

Run some tests and see if this works for you.

Worst case:O((b-a)²)

Best case: O(b-a)

```
#include <iostream>

//Calculate mex starting at myArray[a-1] and ending at myArray[b-1]
int mex(int* myArray, int a, int b){
    int mex = 0; //Lowest positive natural number
    int position = a-1; //To keep track of where you are in the array
    while(position != b){
        if(mex == myArray[position]){
            mex++;
            position = a-1;
        }
        else
            position++;
    }
    return mex;
}

int main(){
    int myArray[10]={0,1,2,3,0,4,5,4,8,6};
    int a = 3;
    int b = 8;
    std::cout << mex(myArray, a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is really fast with short ranges but really slow with long ranges:(

Comment: Worst case scenario is quadratic, maybe there is a way to do it in linear time although I'm not sure if it is possible. As I wrote in the answer the complexity of the algorithm is directly related to the range `b-a` so it is expected to get slower as the range increases.

Comment: This is exactly what he is doing with `while(find(..))` code in the question right?